# Excel pivot condition cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-pivot

how can i set condition inside pivot sum data to refer label row ?
I need to sum data only if row label is equal to specific value.
I'm trying to use standard IF but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you create a helper column at the original table with the `ROW()` function on it? So when you create your pivot table you can use their values as a filter option..

Comment: I can do this, but I'm looking for a solution without to change source table.

Answer (score 0):

Use a vlookup ( within a vlookup.? Others please say if that is necc).  copy paste your row tabels in another column in another sheet/tab and look for them im ur pivot.

Vlookup(a1,sheet2(column),1,0).

Altetnatively u culd just copy paste text only the pivot table results, and use ur if statement there.

But vlookups are superior if statements. So us that is more dynamic/poweful.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a sumproduct function if I were you.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/08/24/excel-sumproduct-function-formula-examples/#Conditionally

To sum Apples sales for North:
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A12="north"), --(B2:B12="apples"), C2:C12)

[image]